# Getting repeated data from a CSV file

Tags: c#, csv

I have a person class like so:

```
class Person
{
    string Id { get; set; }
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

There is a CSV file which has person data like

```
"123","ABC","DEF"
"456","GHI","JKL"
"123","MNO","PQR"
...
```

A person is unique based on the Id.

The CSV is read like this:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(inputFile))
{
    string[] arrCsvData;
    string strLine;

    while ((strLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        arrCsvData = strLine.Split(',');
        this.LoadPersonData(arrCsvData);
    }
 }
```

In `LoadPersonData` a new `Person` object is created and assigned the values from CSV:

```
Person objPerson = new Person();
for (int i = 1; i <= arrCsvData.Length - 1; i++)
{
    // Assign person property values from arrCsvData
}
```

I have a dictionary object in which the key is the ID and the value is the Person object.

```
if(!this.PersonDataCollection.ContainsKey(personKey))
{
    this.PersonDataCollection.Add(objPerson);
}
```

This gives me all the unique Person objects from the CSV file.

I want to create a list of those Person objects which are repeated based on Id in the CSV.
So the list `DuplicatePersons` will have:

```
"123","ABC","DEF"
"123","MNO","PQR"
```

in it.

The bare bones way is to first read all the person objects into a list and then do a LINQ query to get all the duplicates in a separate list. This way I have to create an extra collection just to get the duplicates.

There should be a better way than creating a separate list.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I would use `LINQToCSV`. Parsing CSV files is more complicated than just splitting by `,`. You don't need to code anything, just create your class, and place attributes on it:

```
class Person
{
    [CsvColumn(Name = "ID", ...)]
    string Id { get; set; }
    [CsvColumn(Name = "First Name", ...)]
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    [CsvColumn(Name = "Last Name", ...)]
    string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Then when you read the file using `LINQToCSV`, you get an `IEnumerable<Person>`... and then you can do:

```
IEnumerable<Person> people = ... //read here using LINQToCSV
var grouped = people.GroupBy(p => p.Id);
```

**If you will know the the unique column at runtime, you can do something like this:**

```
string columnName = "Id";
persons.GroupBy(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(columnName).GetValue(x, null));
```

although you will have to see how much it affects you in performance. **Another way that doesn't require Reflection could be:**

```
Dictionary<string, Func<Person, object>> selectors = new Dictionary <string, Func<Person, object>>
            {
                {"Id", x => x.Id},
                {"FirstName", x => x.FirstName},
                {"LastName", x => x.LastName},
            };

string columnName = "Id";
var grouped = people.GroupBy(selectors[columnName]);
```

---

Now, using your approach... what's wrong with creating **another** dictionary?

You could have something like:

```
//Here you will store the duplicated person
//Key: The person Id
//Value: The list of person sharing that same Id
Dictionary<string, IList<Person>> duplicatedPeople;


if(!this.PersonDataCollection.ContainsKey(personKey))
{
    this.PersonDataCollection.Add(objPerson);
}
else
{
    //Here we store all the people with this already existing ID
    IList<Person> duplicatedPeople;

    //If we already have this ID in the dictionary of repeated people
    if (this.duplicatedPeople.TryGetValue(personKey, out duplicatedPeople)) {
        //Just add this new person
        duplicatedPeople.Add(objPerson);
    }
    //If this is the 1st time we found a duplicated person with this ID
    else {
        //We add two persons to the list: this one, and the one from PersonDataCollection.
        duplicatedPeople = new List<Person> { this.PersonDataCollection[personKey], objPerson };
        //Add it to the dictionary
        this.duplicatedPeople.Add(personKey, duplicatedPeople);
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a way to dynamically do this var grouped = people.GroupBy(p => p.Id); I mean can the uniqueness be done at runtime? The user can set the unique column in a config file.

Comment: Thanks Oscar, appreciate your time and patience.

Answer (score 0):

Why Don't you check whether the values are already exist at this point.

```
Person objPerson = new Person();
for (int i = 1; i <= arrCsvData.Length - 1; i++)
{
      // Assign person property values from arrCsvData
}
```

Check your condition here and do what ever you want with the duplicate values at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you do.. there will always be a separate list. It is up to you on how you want them to come about though.

Option 1 - Temporary lists

---

Each time you query your existing dictionary, an in-memory result will be returned. Depending on how big your dataset is.. this may not be what you're after.

Option 2 - Static list

---

Why not just maintain your own list at this point?:

```
if(!this.PersonDataCollection.ContainsKey(personKey))
{
    this.PersonDataCollection.Add(objPerson);
}
else
{
    // Create a new dictionary for the duplicates
    this.DuplicatePersonDataCollection.Add(objPerson);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a single list for all the persons and rather query it with LINQ to get your results:

ie:

```
var persons = new List<Person>();
persons.Add(new Person { Id = "123", FirstName = "AAA", LastName = "XXX" });
persons.Add(new Person { Id = "123", FirstName = "BBB", LastName = "WWW" });
persons.Add(new Person { Id = "456", FirstName = "CCC", LastName = "XXX" });
persons.Add(new Person { Id = "456", FirstName = "DDD", LastName = "YYY" });
persons.Add(new Person { Id = "789", FirstName = "EEE", LastName = "ZZZ" });

var duplicateKeys = persons.GroupBy(p => p.Id).Select(g => new { g.Key, Count = g.Count() }).Where(x => x.Count > 1).ToList().Select(d => d.Key);
var duplicatePersons = persons.Where(p => duplicateKeys.Contains(p.Id)).ToList();
var unique = persons.GroupBy(p => p.Id).ToList();
```